# Why am I seeing a hash rendered to the DOM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a Portfolio website that has a simple view file for projects I have worked on. On my "work" view I render a collection of "technologies" that I used to build a particular product. This is working great, and each technology renders just fine. However, right below the  that renders the technologies the plain hash is also being rendered, and I cannot figure out why.

I am following a tutorial for this and I have double checked that my code is the same as the instructor's.

***Work View***

```
<%= image_tag @work_item.main_image unless @work_item.main_image.nil?  %>

<h1>Title: <%= @work_item.title %></h1>

<em><%= @work_item.subtitle %></em>

<p><%= @work_item.body %></p>

<h2>Technologies Used:</h2>

<%= @work_item.technologies.each do |t| %>
<p><%= t.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

***Schema***

```
 create_table "technologies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "work_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["work_id"], name: "index_technologies_on_work_id"
  end
```

***controller method being used via def show via a before_action***

```
  def set_work
    @work_item = Work.find(params[:id])
  end
```

***Technology Model***

```
class Technology < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :work
end
```

***Work Model***

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :technologies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :technologies,
                                reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs['name'].blank? }
  include Placeholder
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image

  def self.react
    where(subtitle: "React")
  end

  scope :ruby_on_rails, -> { where(subtitle: "Ruby on Rails") }

  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.main_image ||= Placeholder.image_generator(height: 600, width: 400)
    self.thumb_image ||= Placeholder.image_generator(height: 350, width: 200)
  end
end
```

***Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij8h2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `=` in

```
<%= @work_item.technologies.each do |t| %>
```

indicates that you want `@work_item.technologies` to be output to the view.

Instead, use

```
<% @work_item.technologies.each do |t| %>
```

BTW, that's not a `hash`, it's an `enumerable`.